# Wordpress Query overriding default AND operator

Tags: wordpress

I have a wordpress query that is not-using a meta key and needs to override the default `AND` to an `OR`

Code snippet:

```
$args = array(
         'post_type' => 'post',
         'author__in' => $follow_authors,
         'tag_slug__in' => $follows
     );
```

The output statement is `...WHERE 1=1 AND ( wp_term_relationships.term_taxonomy_id IN (71) ) AND wp_posts.post_author IN (3)...`

I can't find a way to make the `..) AND wp.posts.post_author...` to be an `OR`

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should get you started:

```
$meta_query_args = array(
    'relation' => 'OR', // Optional, defaults to "AND"
    array(
        'key'     => '_my_custom_key',
        'value'   => 'Value I am looking for',
        'compare' => '='
    )
);
$meta_query = new WP_Meta_Query( $meta_query_args );
```

There is more in-depth explanation and examples here: https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Meta_Query

Comment: I have tried this but since what I am querying is not a meta key/value then I am not sure it will work properly.

Comment: You could use standard SQL and just type out OR. You don't have to do queries the Wordpress way

Comment: save the query as a string in a variable called `$query`, then use wordpress to call the query
`$wpq = new WP_Query($query);`